# Wordpress PerfectPixel theme

Tags: wordpress-theming

I have a problem with my wordpress theme, I have been translating an english page into French, on  the english page, the pictures appear properly on the mainfrontpage but it doesn't appear on the french homepage.

Here is the english page: http://www.interactioncamps.org/
Here is the french page:

Comment: i dont have any experience in wordpress but looks like your jquery function of slider is not working when french page is open

Answer (score 0):

However you're calling your jquery.cycle plugin, the French page does not appear to be passing it any slides. Take a look at your browser's JavaScript console on the French page:

```
[cycle] terminating; too few slides: 0
jquery.cycle.all.js:33
```

Without seeing some reference code it's tough to say exactly what the problem is, but that should point you in the right direction.